# Why can’t I disable the Update Manager module?

Tags: 9

In drupal 7 we had the ability to disable the update module, but in Drupal 8,9+ we can't do that.

How do we disable the message:

> There is a security update available for your version of Drupal.

Comment: Maybe you should just perform the security updates.

Comment: @sonfd and risk breaking the entire site with custom modules made for a prior version of drupal?

Comment: It's a mistake if security updates are not part of your ongoing maintenance plan.

Comment: @sonfd if a client doesn't want to pay for it. what do you do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot disable any module in Drupal 9—"disabling" modules is no longer possible. You uninstall them. [Uninstall](https://www.drupal.org/docs/extending-drupal/uninstalling-modules) the Update Manager module.

Comment: It's greyed out on the module page, but drush pm-uninstall update did the trick.

Comment: All modules are grayed out once they are installed. You have to switch to the Uninstall tab.